# use api to login to my asp.net website

Tags: sql, asp.net, api, authentication

I'm a asp.net web developer, I have  a new system to build, the system is connected with api contains the user, password, and Permissions
I want help me with the concept to build system, with login from api, usually I used a membership or identity to build uses, password and permissions.

so how can i deal with user not exist in tables at my database.

Comment: Have an appropriate authority grant the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write a comment, but I think you need to know how to deal and use OAuth 2.0 for authentication which usually we use it when we want to get personal data  from third party, here is some links, I wish these links help you.
 
[Intro to OAuth 2.0](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) 
[Tutorialspoint OAuth 2.0](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/oauth2.0/) 
[Authentication](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/)